# JS/JQuery and iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From one hand, I am aware about cross-domain security and JS. From the other, I hope, somebody might have found a solution, perhaps. I have an iframe, which loads a form from another site. On submit, it opens in the same window, but I want to change that with `form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");` code. But, it does not work with "foreign" iframe. Any ideas?
Here is a sample code, where I try to get access to iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Inserting Textarea Value into an iFrame</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    textarea, iframe{
        display: block;
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
    iframe{
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateIframe(){
        var myFrame = $("#myframe").contents().find('body');
        var textareaValue = $("textarea").val();
        myFrame.html(textareaValue);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Type HTML or text here..."></textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="updateIframe()">Insert Content</button>    
    <iframe src="https://onlinebistro.ua/iframe/8f14ae16bfc49a66aadfc75e67b6cf84/searching/" id="myFrame1" style="border: none; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; height: 335px;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot change contents of iframe from other domains.

Comment: The only way I can think of, is to write your own form locally (with the same action pointing to the foreign place), and the target attribute changed. Because as @RokoC.Buljan said, you can't change contents that come from other domains.

Comment: Is there any trick to avoid JS cross-domain restrictions? Can I write an outer CORS   proxy component with  Access-Control-Allow-Origin * option? Or, may be, I can get the remote content with AJAX and insert it into my page as a local content, and then, change it? If I am rigtht, where can I find any example?